# Python 3 Not Updating in Shell on Mac Mini M1

Tags: terminal, mac-mini, python, apple-silicon

My Mac Mini M1 shipped with Python 3.8.5.

I first installed Anaconda, then downloaded Python 3.9.1 (macOS 64-bit universal2 installer),  installed that and ran Update Shell Profile.command.

IDLE runs the correct version (3.9.1) however typing python3 --version at command line yields: Python 3.8.5

where python3 results in the following:

/Users/fa/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3

How do I get the shell to point to the most recent version (3.9.1)?

Comment: What is the output of ‘which python3.9’ ? And why don’t you use python3’s built in venv or python module pyvenv to manage all the versions ?

Comment: which python3.9 outputs

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9

how do I utilize vent's to direct it to the correct path? sorry, a little new to this.

Comment: If you are using conda use conda rather than venv to control things. However that is. Not the issue here. Have you tried in a new terminal which and where should give the same answer. So the first thing to rule out is has the shell cached some information

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/410284/237

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pyenv` to manage your python3 versions installed on your system.

To install `pyenv`:

You can do the following:

```bsh
# if you dont have homebrew already, install it by:
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

```bsh
# install pyenv with homebrew
brew install pyenv
```

```bsh
# source pyenv in your .bash_profile if you are using bash
echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

```bsh
# source pyenv in your .zshrc if you are using zsh
echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Open a new terminal or source your bash_profile or shell profile by: `source ~/.bash_profile` or `source ~/.zshrc`.

Now to install a new version, you can check the list by:

```bsh
pyenv install -l | grep anaconda
```

Find the version you want to install, and install it by:

```bsh
pyenv install <python-version-to-install>
```

Now you will be able to see all the different python versions that you have installed by:

```bsh
pyenv versions
```

You can choose any of the above output as your global Python from the previous command by:

```bsh
pyenv global <your-installed-version>
```

For more details see their git repo at: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv